# FLEX: How to know when a dialog created throw PopUpManager Closes

Tags: apache-flex, dialog, popup

Is there a easy way to figure out consistently when a Dialog closes that has been created through PopUpManager.  I would have suspected some type of message or callback mechanism, but there does not seem to be.  In one case I use the WindowTitle component and event that only fires the CLOSE if someone presses the close and give no message when the dialog actually closes.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the solution to all needs.  But, if you're using a TitleWindow, just listen to the close event:

Something like this:

```
var win : IFlexDisplayObject = PopUpManager.createPopUp(Application.application as DisplayObject, TitleWindow, false) as IFlexDisplayObject;
win.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, onClose);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);
```

And the title window should be something like this:

```
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" showCloseButton="true" close="closeHandler(event)">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        protected function closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
        }           
    ]]>
</mx:Script></mx:TitleWindow>
```

Comment: That is what I originally thought, but when I looked into it the CloseEvent only happens when you click the "X".  The solution I implemented was to create a DialogBaseEvent class with APPLY and CANCEL events and fire those when user hits APPLY or CANCEL.   I then use those events to trigger the close properly removing the event listeners I needed to remove.  Not ideal,  but in my case it will serve its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually call the close using something like this:

```
dispatchEvent(new CloseEvent(CloseEvent.CLOSE, true, false));
PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
```

Then add an event listener that looks at the popups `closeevent.close` and do your work after that.

Works for me.